# Swig C++ with multiple includes to Python module

Tags: python, c++, swig

I need to export some C++ code to Python modules. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "3.h"
#include "4.h"
#include "5.h"
#include "6.h"

using namespace EXMPL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Since I have a lot of custom includes what is the preferred way to handle this? Do I have to make .i interface files for each include and then add it to the main interface file?

How should I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a single header file for this source code in which you then do all the includes. So *file.h* contains:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "3.h"
#include "4.h"
#include "5.h"
#include "6.h"
```

and then:

```
/* file.i */
 %module file
 %{
#include "file.h"
%}

%include "file.h"
```

The first step is of course not necessary. You can also just add all the includes in one interface file

```
/* file.i */
 %module file
 %{
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "3.h"
#include "4.h"
#include "5.h"
#include "6.h"
%}

%include "1.h"
%include "2.h"
%include "3.h"
%include "4.h"
%include "5.h"
%include "6.h"
```